# Most battery friendly periodic task method

Tags: android

I want to run a specific task every 3 or 5 minutes, I know there are a few options to achieve this like [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler), [Jobservice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService), [Alarmanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) and so on, my question is:

Which one is the most efficient in terms of resources consumption?

Comment: Its not that simple.  How much inaccuracy can you accept?  Do you want it to work only if your Activity is running?  Only if the phone screen is recently on?  No matter what? Do you want it to persist even if the phone is rebooted?  Different requirements give different answers.

Comment: Hi! I want to run that task as long as the device is on.

Comment: Then Handler isn't even in consideration.  JobScheduler and AlarmManager both are (JS is a nicer interface to AM).  But you won't get 3-5 minutes due to Doze mode, unless you can get your user to whitelist your app.  You'll get every 15 minutes when the phone's screen is off.  See:  https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: Looks like there's now WorkManager too hahaha. What's next? SuperDuperAlarmWorker? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JobScheduler is the best and the recommended option by google. To replace background services and broadcasts which do periodic operations, Google suggests to use JobScheduler only.
Refer this article :
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: JobScheduler by itself now officially is garbage. Use WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager ;-) Next week stay tuned for that to be out dated. They need to pay people to do something.